Inverting the Normalization of a matrix of eigenvalues using numpy.linalg.eig()
I've been given a matrix [[4,-1,6],[2,1,6],[2,-1,8]] and been asked to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors using the Numpy library, specifically the numpy.linalg.eig() command. The command spits out the eigenvectors as normalized, but I need them as whole numbers. How can I undo this normalization of the matrix of eigenvectors using Numpy?
Code:
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eig

a1=np.array([[4,-1,6],[2,1,6],[2,-1,8]])
w, v = np.linalg.eig(a1)

Note: I have to use Numpy, not a substitute library.
I've tried using standard methods to undo normalization, but they haven't worked or gave wildly incorrect answers.

Please give an example for which you already know the expected result. Do you mean you want the real and imaginary components to be whole numbers? Is that the only requirement (e.g. integer multiples of each vector also satisfy your requirements)? Note that this is only possible in special cases.

Plus, even when possible, there is never a unique way to do it. So, you have to specify more what criteria you want to use to choose among the infinite number of possible eigenvectors (also, note that nothing says that, in numpy internal code, the eigenvectors were "more integer" before normalization. So "undo normalization", and "have integer values" are two different, maybe contradictory, objectives. Even tho, with teacher examples eigenvectors, using classical solving methods, often happens to be whole before normalization, that is not a general rule. It is just what happens ...

in unrealistic school exercise, because teachers know what techniques they taught you, so they know what you will probably do to get an eigenvector, so they can predict which ones (among the infinite number of correct answers) you will find, if you follow exactly the same steps than the ones they've shown in class, and they can try to choose exercise statement so that those happens to be integers. That is a totally specific, unrealistic and artificial phenomenon for school statement. Not a general rule, and certainly not what would happen with real life examples)

@MattHaberland I know the expected result for the example given, eigenvalues are 2,2, and 9, and eigenvectors are [1,2,0] , [-3,0,1], and [1,1,1] respectively. My reason for stating "whole numbers" is because I know the answer contains whole numbers. I would want the final answer to be all whole numbers, meaning if something was 0.5, it would be scaled up.

@chrslg I'm aware that there are an infinite number of eigenvectors, I'm just looking for one that hasn't been normalized to a unit vector. For the example I gave, I know the eigenvectors are [1,2,0] , [-3,0,1], and [1,1,1]. I'm trying to find code that converts the normalized eigenvalues to the known ones.

But if there are ∞ eigenvectors, there are ∞-1 non normalized ones (∞-2, since you can still choose the sign when normalizing). ∞-2 is still a lot of choices. Which one do you want ? :D

Note that what I say here is a rhetorical question. I know which one you want (you gave even the explicit numerical answer). But is to explain why there is no such thing as "the non-normalized version" that numpy could give. The one you want has absolutely nothing particular from a math perspective. Except indeed for the fact that it is made of whole integers, but that never happen, except for specific examples built by a math teacher. Mathematically, that is simply not a thing. And there is no reason for numpy to deal with that.

@chrslg I guess what I'm saying is that I want the one with non-reducible terms, meaning [1,2,0], not [2,4,0]. And the problem with what you're saying is that other libraries other than numpy do give that version. Using sympy gives the non-normalized version, and I would be using that if it wasn't specifically in the instructions to use numpy.

All that being said, if you know for sure that there exist a whole integer version of the eigenvectors, and that the normalized vectors are just a whole integer vector divided by a norm, that is also the square root of an integer, you could try to code a search algorithm, to find which factor (square root of an integer) to multiply the normalized vector with, so that it is integer. That factor might be a non-diagonal matrix tho, because if an eigenspace has a non-1 dimension (which is the case here: eigen val 2 match a 2d-eigenspace), then, it might be not doable by just scaling vectors)

@ChefB I am sure some library do that. But understand that they certainly guarantee nothing about those vectors, and in particular not that the result is integer or anything. They just happen to fall on the same eigenvectors that you teachers used (because they probably use the same algorithm). But that is just random (and artificial luck due to the fact that this is a school statement). Again, there is no such thing as a "non-reductible integer" version. Nor anything like a canonical non normalized vesion.

@chrslg Ok, but knowing that all of the problems I will be doing will have the same exact "luck", is there a way to find A solution, even if it's not THE solution? Or a way to undo the extra step numpy takes to normalize the eigenvector between -1 and 1?

As I said, maybe you could try to search for a factor. For [1,1,1] that is even quite easy. Even if you ignore (or pretend to ignore) the fact that factor has to be √3, you can try all of them: hyp=np.sqrt(np.arange(1,20)[:,None]); rest=(v[:,0]*hyp)%1; hyp[np.argmin(np.max(np.minimum(rest, 1-rest), axis=1))]*v[:,0] is [1,1,1] (aka the closest thing to a whole integer you get when multiplying vector 0 by a factor √1 to √19)

But for the other, see that there is no factor at all. It is not just "normalization". v[:,1] and v[:,2] (the eigenvectors associated with eigenvalue 2) would look like [3*something, 0, -something] and [something, 2*something, 0]. They don't. The aren't even any 0 in them. So it is not just a factor, a normalization. [-3,0,1] and [1,2,0] aren't just the "non-normalized" version of them. They are a linear combination of them.

@chrslg so there's absolutely no way to undo the normalization that numpy does and get an answer that looks something like the "by-hand" version?

Are you sure the assignment wants you to have python return the eigenvectors with purely integer values? If the teacher has tried it then they know it won't return them. Maybe the teacher just wants you to show the result from Python and show that the result you get by hand is equivalent (by normalizing them)?

@jared The teacher challenged me to find a way to undo the normalization in Python itself. He's looking for code that returns the same (or equivalent) eigenvectors that would occur by hand calculations.

If that's the entire goal, then isn't it cheating to ask us to help you with that?

@jared it would be cheating if it was a graded assignment or had any weight value to it. When I say challenged, I mean more like "exercise left to the reader" type thing. Getting an answer won't affect the class or anything, it's just something I'm trying to do

Starting with the original eigenvalue decomposition:
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=200)
from numpy.linalg import eig
A = np.array([[4, -1, 6], [2, 1, 6], [2, -1, 8]])
eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(A)
eigenvalues = np.diag(eigenvalues)

According to NumPy, the eigenvectors are:
array([[ 0.57735027+0.j        , -0.29157823-0.33778223j, -0.29157823+0.33778223j],
       [ 0.57735027+0.j        , -0.88637126+0.j        , -0.88637126-0.j        ],
       [ 0.57735027+0.j        , -0.0505358 +0.11259408j, -0.0505358 -0.11259408j]])

and the eigenvalues:
array([[9.+0.00000000e+00j, 0.+0.00000000e+00j, 0.+0.00000000e+00j],
       [0.+0.00000000e+00j, 2.+3.14018492e-16j, 0.+0.00000000e+00j],
       [0.+0.00000000e+00j, 0.+0.00000000e+00j, 2.-3.14018492e-16j]])

The first eigenvector is already real and corresponds with an eigenvalue of 9. We can get an all-integer version as:
e1 = eigenvectors[:, 0] / eigenvectors[0, 0]
e1  # array([1.+0.j, 1.+0.j, 1.+0.j])

The other two eigenvectors correspond with repeated eigenvalues of 2, so linear combinations of these eigenvectors are also eigenvectors corresponding with an eigenvalue of 2. We can get one whole number eigenvector as:
e2 = eigenvectors[:, 1] - eigenvectors[:, 2]
e2 = e2 / e2[-1]
e2  # array([-3.-0.j,  0.+0.j,  1.+0.j])

As for the last one, there are probably more direct ways, but inspection led me to:
e3 = eigenvectors[:, 1] + eigenvectors[:, 2]
e3 = e3 / e3[-1] - e2
e3 = e3 / e3[0]
e3  # array([1.00000000e+00+0.j, 2.00000000e+00-0.j, 1.26597084e-17-0.j])

The problem statement doesn't mention that the procedure needs to be automated. I think that would be a separate question.

Another thing you can try is to perturb the data:
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eig
A = np.array([[4, -1, 6], [2, 1, 6], [2, -1, 8.000000001]])
eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(A)
eigenvalues = np.diag(eigenvalues)

Now we have all real eigenvalues:
array([[9., 0., 0.],
       [0., 2., 0.],
       [0., 0., 2.]])

and eigenvectors:
array([[-5.77350269e-01, -7.02247189e-01, -4.47213429e-01],
       [-5.77350269e-01, -7.02246551e-01, -8.94427274e-01],
       [-5.77350269e-01,  1.17041304e-01, -6.93823981e-08]])

The first can be recognized as [1, 1, 1] (by dividing by the first element), the second can be recognized as [-6, -6, 1] (by dividing by the third element), and the third can be recognized as [1, 2, 0] (by dividing by the first element).

There seems to be an issue with the second eigenvector. When I run the code for the e2 eigenvector, I do not get [-3,0,1], but instead [-2.47116, 1.05769, 1].

You may get different results on different machines. Fortunately, you can reproduce these results on Colab. I included the results of eig in my answer so you can see what is going on. You can adapt the ideas to your own data if it is different.
